# Question about the form of returning value of String[] in java

Tags: java, arrays, unit-testing

When there is a getter method with a return type of String[],

for example:

```
private static Map<Integer, String[]> map = new HashMap();


public static void setterMethod(int id, String number, String address) {

    String[] arr = new String[2];
    arr[0] = "number";
    arr[1] = "address";
    map.put(id, arr);
}

public String[] getterMethod(int id) {
    String[] arr = new String[]{map.get(id)[0], map.get(id)[1]};
    return arr;
}
```

When we do a unit test, I need to do something like:

```
Assert.assertEquals(getterMethod(1), Arrays.asList("number", "Address"));
```

but this test will fail since `getterMethod(1)` will print out something like: `String@a1b2c223d`

How can we make `getterMethod()` to return in the form of `[number, address]` whilest maintaining the return type of the `getterMethod`?

Comment: `Arrays.asList(getterMethod(1))`

Comment: Use Arrays.equals instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here.

First, `gettMethod` retuns an array of Strings (`String[]`) and `Arrays.asList` returns a `List<String>`, so they will never be equal. Instead of `Arrays.asList`, you should create an array.
Second, arrays don't overwrite the `equals(Object)` method, so you need to use a different assertion method that handles arrays:

```java
Assert.assertArraysEquals(getterMethod(1), new String[]{"number", "Address"});
```